# not able to save belongs_to association record which is nested

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, associations, nested-forms

I have a typical model controller realtionship with lot of nested forms.

Here are the details :-

article.rb :-

```
belongs_to :author
accepts_nested_attributes_for :author
```

author.rb :-

```
attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name
has_many :articles
```

project.rb

```
has_many :work_pairs
  has_many :source_articles, :through => :work_pairs

accepts_nested_attributes_for :work_pairs
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :source_articles
```

projects/new.html.slim

```
= semantic_form_for @project, :html => { :id => 'project_form' } do |form|
  = form.inputs do
    = form.input :user_id, :as => :hidden, :value => current_user.id

    = form.semantic_fields_for :source_articles do |article|
      = article.input :name_article, :label => "Name of the Article"

      = article.semantic_fields_for :author do |author|
        = author.input :first_name
        = author.input :last_name
```

projects_controller.rb

```
def new
    return unless require_login
    new! do
      @title = t('projects.new.title')
      @project.rewards.build
      @project.work_pairs.build
      @project.source_articles.build
      @project.source_articles.first.build_author
      @project.source_articles.first.build_publisher
    end
  end
```

However when my author record is not getting saved in the database it does not show any error either.

When I try to access author from console by doing this :-

```
p = Project.first
p.source_articles.first.author
```

I get nil as output, can someone let me know what is the issue ?

Answer (score 1):

You can check the errors by

```
p.errors.messages
```

I'd wager that there is a validation that is not passing.